# cakephp Stop AUTOLOADING models/tables

Tags: cakephp, model, autoload

I have a model named 'Object' which loads the 'Objects' table

I have a controller 'TestObjectController' which loads the Object model

```
<?php
class TestObjectController extends AppController 
{

    var $name = "TestObject";


    function beforeFilter() 
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }


    function index()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }


    function showall()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->loadModel("Object");
    }

}
```

But when i actually run the controller 'http://localhost:8002/TestObject' it gives me this error '**Missing Database Table**'

```
$___dataForView =   array(
    "model" => "TestObject",
    "table" => "test_objects",
.....
```

Im guessing its trying to load the model '**TestObject**' and the table '**test_object**'

is there a way to stop it from autoloading the model/table

This is my model

```
class Objects extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = false;
    var $name = 'Object';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use this code at your controller:

```
<?php
class TestObjectController extends AppController 
{

    var $name = "TestObject";
    var $uses = NULL;
```

$uses tell the controller here there is no table to be loaded.